# Correct #Value! in a search equation

Tags: excel-formula

I am searching a cell for a particular word ... in this instance the word is "cabinet".  When the word is present I would like my cell to equal the sum of two other cells, when the word is not present I would like it to equal 0.

I am using Cell `A1` and The equation I am using is `=IF(Search("Cabinet",B1),F1,"0")`
When "cabinet" is present in the cell it returns the correct dollar value, if cabinet is not present it returns #value! instead of the "0".    If it helps, cell F1 contains the the equation of B1 x E1 ie. 12x$80.  Here is an example

```
960      Base Cabinet   12  L/F  $80.00  $960.00
#VALUE!  Countertop     12  L/F  $20.00  $240.00
```

Answer (score 0):

The check would be to see if the `SEARCH` function returned a number. This indicates that the search term was found. If it is not found then `SEARCH` returns #VALUE! which is the error you are receiving. With `ISNUMBER` we can see if the search was found or not.

`=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Cabinet", B1)), F1, 0)`

Note that it is not necessary to wrap the *0* in quotes. Doing so reduces the zero to a text representation of a number, not a true number.

Comment: Better to use `IfError`

Comment: @chrisneilsen - I actually wrote an alternative formula using `IFERROR` but discarded that portion of my reply due to the complexity of incorporating it into the If statement. `=IFERROR(IF(SEARCH("Cabinet", B1), F1), 0)` just didn't seem like that much of an improvement and loses pre-Excel 2007 compatibility. A better formula may have been `=IF(COUNTIF(B1, "*Cabinet*"), F1, 0)` but the question was about `SEARCH`.

Comment: how about `=IFERROR((SEARCH("Cabinet", B1)>0)*F1,0)`

Comment: and anyway, `Search` is in aid of "what have you tried?"  proposing a different function would be OK too.

Comment: As for pre-2007 support - it's about time a decade old, out of support version is no longer considered the default verion.  If the OP wants 2003 support (s)he needs to say so.